# Video Hardware Acceleration Causing Weird colors

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, color-profiles, hardware-acceleration

I am using Windows 10,
On the start menu, there is a tile that displays Images from your folders.
Clicking on the image brings up a tab that sits on the right hand of the screen, which also contains a settings option.
I was messing around trying to disable windows showing my images in the start menu & I click disable hardware acceleration. Even though I knew this had nothing to do with what I was trying to achieve. now when-ever I view videos
The colors are all messed up and enableing/disableing this setting doesn't seem to do anything, even with a system restart. It doesn't matter whether they are videos I have downloaded or videos that are on various different websites. Using Vlc media player or MPC-Hc The Colors are inverted, but Not 100% inverted. Just mainly Blue with some other accents. I have tried nearly every setting I can Aswell as rolling back drivers for the graphics card and monitor. Does Anybody know a fix for this issue.

The Only thread I can find that is similar is this one:

[Why are my video colors getting messed up?](https://superuser.com/questions/1293872/why-are-my-video-colors-getting-messed-up?rq=1)
But it doesn't seem like he is having the same issue as me, as the colors are not the same & he has not mentioned anything about Hardware Acceleration.

Comment: "I click disable hardware acceleration" So have you tried enabling it again?

Comment: @DavidPostill  Yes it says this in the question, have tried enableing & disableing & restart on both and it does nothing....